# async_connect() timeout with multiple threads performing io_service.run()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to implement async_connect() with a timeout.

```
    async_connect_with_timeout(socket_type & s,
        std::function<void(BoostAndCustomError const & error)> const & connect_handler,
        time_type timeout);
```

When operation completes `connect_handler(error)` is called with `error` indicating operation result (including timeout).

I was hoping to use code from [timeouts example 1.51](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp). The biggest difference is that I am using multiple worker threads performing io_service.run().

What changes are necessary to keep the example code working?

My issues are:

1. When  calling :

   ```
   Start() {
       socket_.async_connect(Handleconnect);
       dealine_.async_wait(HandleTimeout);
   }
   ```

   `HandleConnect()` can be completed in another thread even before `async_wait()` (unlikely but possible). Do I have to `strand` wrap `Start()`, `HandleConnect()`, and `HandleTimeout()`?
2. What if `HandleConnect()` is called first without error, but `deadline_timer.cancel()` or `deadline_timer.expires_from_now()` fails because `HandleTimeout()` "have been queued for invocation in the near future"? Looks like example code lets `HandleTimeout()` close socket. Such behavior (timer closes connection after we happily started some operations after connect) can easily lead to serious headache.
3. What if `HandleTimeout()` and `socket.close()` are called first. Is it possible to `HandlerConnect()` be already "queued" without error? Documentation says: "Any asynchronous send, receive or connect operations will be cancelled immediately, and will complete with the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error". What does "immediately" mean in multithreading environment?

Comment: In what thread `Start()` function is expected to run? Is it one of the `io_service` threads or some other "user" thread?

Comment: @IgorR. I am using thread pool from [HTTP Server 3 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) To be more precise: my "user" threads use io_service.post().

Comment: @IgorR. `Start()` would be called from `io_service` thread calling `io_service.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should wrap with strand each handler, if you want to prevent their parallel execution in different threads. I guess some completion handlers would access `socket_` or the timer, so you'll definitely have to wrap `Start()` with a strand as well. But wouldn't it be much more simple to use io_service-per-CPU model, i.e. to base your application on `io_service` pool? IMHO, you'll get *much* less headache.
2. Yes, it's possible. Why is it a headache? The socket gets closed because of a "false timeout", and you start re-connection (or whatever) procedure just as if it were closed due to a network failure.
3. Yes, it's also possible, but again, it shouldn't cause any problem for correctly designed program: if in `HandleConnect` you try to issue some operation on a closed socket, you'll get the appropriate error. Anyway, when you attempt to send/receive data you don't really know the current socket/network status.

Comment: 1) `async_connect_with_timeout()` would be used in a few applications. I can't limit them to one particular threading model.  2) I disagree. When I call `connect_handler()` without errors there can be no "false timeout" closing it afterwards. Imagine if my function was `boost::asio::async_connect()`. Calling `connect_handler()` means operation is **completed**.  3) You did not answer my question here. I want facts not slogans like "correctly designed".  Main question was: "is boost example ok?".

Comment: @Daszek 2) If you using asio::strand there is not such problems. 3) *What does "immediately" mean in multithreading environment?* - not multithreading, but in async environment. This means callback will be called from current handler right when you call `cancel()` (not queued for execution).

Comment: @PSIAlt 3) I said **multithreading** because of multiple threads calling io_service.run(). Please lets stick with `close()`. I don't want to deal with `cancel()`. Also what you said seems to contradict IgorR.'s statment.

Comment: @Daszek I think `close()` dealing with `cancel()` for you. Did you checked? If you dont want to check anything we cant help.

Comment: @PSIAlt I checked. That is why I stick to `close()`.